# For EmberJs models, why is recommended not to override the `init` method

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Why is it recommended not to `super` override an EmberJs model objects `init` method?

I implemented this code, and it is working perfectly fine (for now, I guess):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Object.extend({
    init() {
        this._super();
        if (!this.get('type')) {
            this.set('type', this.get('typeDefault'));
        }
    },
});
```

The EmberJs docs on `init` are [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_init)

Here is one article not recommending it.

https://dockyard.com/blog/2014/04/28/dont-override-init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with overriding init. In some cases you have to. The common alternative is to use the `init` event, but this event should actually be called `afterInit` because it is called after the object is created and using `set` can cause observers to fire in that case.

Here is an article refuting the one you cited: https://dockyard.com/blog/2015/10/19/2015-dont-dont-override-init

The correct way to call `init`:

```
init(...args) {
    this._super(...args);
    // ...
}
```

or if you are not using Babel:

```
init: function() {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why some people do not recommend it is cited in your referenced article. If you do forget to call `this._super(...args)` and your parent model does override the `init` function as well, the parent models init will not be called!

As long as you always call the super class, overriding the `init` function does no harm.